# Prove $2^{2n+7} \equiv 2 (mod 3)$ for all integer and non-negative number n.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, integers

Originally, I want to prove this problem:

for all integer and non-negative number $n$,

$$\frac{1}{3}\times2^{2n+7}+\frac{37}{3} \equiv 0\quad(\text{mod}\space3)$$

I tried like this:

$$\frac{1}{3}\times2^{2n+7}+\frac{37}{3} = \frac{1}{3}(2^{2n+7}+37)$$

therefore $2^{2n+7}+37$ must be $\equiv0\space(\text{mod}\space3)$ and greater than or equal to $3$.

Since $2^{2n+7}+37$ is bigger than $37$(for all $n$), we can ignore the latter.

By the way, $37 \equiv 1(\text{mod}\space3)$.  Therefore $2^{2n+7} \equiv 2(\text{mod}\space3)$.

I stuck here. is there any way to prove this?

and following calculation correct?

$$2^{2n+7} =  2^7\times 2^{2n}\quad \text{and}\quad 2^7 \equiv 2 (\text{mod}\space3)$$Therefore,

$$2^{2n+7}  =2^7\times 2^{2n} \equiv  2\times 2^{2n} (\text{mod}\space3)$$

Comment: $(2^2)^n \cdot 2^7 \equiv 1^n \cdot 128 \equiv 128 \equiv 2 \text{ (mod } 3).$

Comment: @Will199 just note that $2^{2n+7}\equiv(-1)^{2n+7}\equiv-1\equiv2 \pmod{3}$

Comment: @Evariste True. Indeed, more straightforward.

Comment: The original problem you're trying to prove isn't true in general. For example, ${1\over3}\times2^{11}+{37\over3}={2085\over3}=695\equiv2$ mod $3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Will199 and Evariste.

for all integer and non-negative number $n$,

$2^{n}\equiv (-1)^{n} \equiv -1($when n is odd$)$ or $1$(when n is even) $(mod \quad3)$

$2n+7$ is always odd because $2n$ is even and $7$ is odd and even+odd=odd.

So, $2^{2n+7}\equiv (-1)^{2n+7} \equiv -1 \equiv 2 \quad(mod \quad3)$.